# Arquivos não aparecem no repositório Git

Tags: git

Criei um novo projeto aqui e depois subi ele para o servidor, porém quando tento acessar o repositório via URL aparece uma página do Apache com o nome: `Index of / site`, ou seja minha pasta do projeto esta vazia, mas quando dou um `git clone` em um computador de um amigo usando o mesmo IP e o mesmo nome do projeto que o Git pucha todos os arquivos e eu consigo visualizá-los no *localhost*. Por quê isso está acontecendo no servidor? Por quê eu não consigo visualizar os arquivos no servidor?

O repositório já estava no servidor, mas mesmo assim não mostrava a listagem de pastas e arquivos que contém lá.

Nos trabalhando em servidor que funciona na rede local, eu excluir o projeto antigo que estava no servidor e depois enviei o meu projeto para o mesmo repositório que já estava criado.

Sequência de passos:

1. `git clone ssh://@192.168.100.19/repositorios/git/api.git`
2. `cd api`
3. `rm -fr *`
4. `git add --all`
5. `git commit -m "removendo projeto antigo"`

**OBS**: antes de eu dar o `rm -fr` ali eu entrava na URL e não listava nada.

1. `cd ..`
2. `cd apinova`
3. `git checkout master`
4. `git remote add origin ssh://@192.168.100.19/repositorios/git/api.git`
5. `git pull origin master` Não deu erro aqui -> repositório atualizado
6. `git push -u origin master`

Enviei os arquivos para o servidor, mas quando acesso a URL não aparece nada. Aparece a página do Apache que é a: `Index of /apinova`, sem nada no diretório.

Comment: Não sei. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes sobre a estrutura do seu servidor? Quais os comandos quer utilizou? Como está organizado o servidor? Como ele está configurado? Etc.

Comment: tentei explicar melhor.

Comment: O repositório fica no diretório raiz do Apache?

Comment: @Lucas faz um teste e depois comente o resultado. Apague qualquer cópia do projeto, recrie-o com o `git glone` conforme vez. Faça uma alteração simples. Aplique o `git status` e tire um print da resposta no terminal e adicione a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que aconteceu é o seguinte, temos uma pasta onde fica os arquivos por exemplo:

api.git

Quando enviamos um projeto para o servidor enviamos para essa pastas e ela automaticamente cria uma pasta do projeto com todo o código fonte em /var/www.

Enfim o que estava errado ?

dentro da pasta api.git, tem um arquivo que se chama config,dentro desse arquivo config só estava a configuração padrão então tive que acrescentar algumas informações olhando como base os repositórios já criados, exemplo da configuração padrão:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
```

Exemplo do que eu fiz para o sistema funcionar, trocarei algumas informacoes abaixo não vou por aqui configuracoes do meu servidor, exemplo:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@ip-servidor/repositorios/git/api.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Fis isso ai e funcionou, agora o meu projeto dentro de /var/www/api eta sendo atualizado automaticamente.